# How to create a direct access to a wine32 program?

Tags: scripts, wine

I'm trying to create a direct access to Office Word, Excel and Powerpoint 2007 (I have to use those programs). I have configured them correctly with wine, and running for example:

```
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/carlos/.wine32 wine /home/carlos/.wine32/drive_c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Office/Office12/WINWORD.EXE
```

it opens Word perfectly.

But I don't want to type or copy/paste that line everytime, so I want to create a direct access that executes that line when I double-click on it, maybe a script or something.

Can anyone offer me some help?

Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options 1. Create a bash script that can be started from the command line or 2. Create a desktop shortcut
**Note:** These methods are untested as I'm not at my ubuntu machine right now (just going from memory). YMMV also depending on which apps and desktop enviroment you are using.
Option 1. Bash script
(i) Open you favourite word processor/notepad app
(ii) Cut and paste the following:
`#!/bin/bash<br/>
WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/carlos/.wine32 wine /home/carlos/.wine32/drive_c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Office/Office12/WINWORD.EXE`
(iii) Save the file as something like `word.sh` and close the word processor/notepad app
(iv) In the file manager, bring up the properties for this file. Tick the option to make this file **executable**
(v) Now you can call this from the command line as such `./word.sh`
Option 2. Create a shortcut
(i) Open file manager
(ii) Navigate to where `word.exe` is saved
(iii) Right-click on the exe file
(iv) Select 'Create link' from the context menu
(v) Right-click on the newly created shortcut
(vi) Edit the command field (change from `word.exe` to `WINEARCH=win32 WINEPREFIX=/home/carlos/.wine32 wine /home/carlos/.wine32/drive_c/Program\ Files/Microsoft\ Office/Office12/WINWORD.EXE`
(vii) Close the properties dialog box by clicking "Close" button
You should be able to launch Word by clicking (double-clicking?) on the shortcut.

Comment: Did the second, it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.